# AxWMPLib CODEC Issues - No Sound when playing some Movies

Tags: c#, media-player

I have a small basic Media Player configured using AxWMPLib to play Movies on command. The URI gets passed to the Media Player through the App Args on startup.

```
if (appArgs.Length > 0)
{
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = appArgs[0].ToString();
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

All movies play but some have no Sound? All Movies I can play in Windows Media Player and they have sound.

I am using the KLite Codec pack.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is now resolved:

I updated from K-Lite Codec Pack 9.8.5 to [K-Lite Codec Pack 10.2.3](http://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_standard.htm) and the problem now has resolved itself.

My Application build was set to x64 (Any CPU). I ticked the x64 option on the installation:

[image]

Its Quite Likely that simply changing the application to x86 instead of (Any CPU) may have solved the problem.

Also it is possible that simply upgrading K-Lite Codec Pack 10.2.3  solved this issue.